# Set image at top of page

Tags: html, css

I want to set the following [image](https://www.sololearn.com/Uploads/html-css.jpg) above my menu list.

Can I use `<header>` tag for this purpose — if I can then how?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "above" in what way? can you create an image of how you want that?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aXMBjKxGvk and then put that image above your `ul`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i add a background image to my header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349112/how-do-i-add-a-background-image-to-my-header)

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in header tag, you can fine updated code below

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://www.sololearn.com/Uploads/html-css.jpg " alt="" />
</header>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you want to achieve but from your question i understand that you want the image to be above the menu. so there it is :

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.sololearn.com/Uploads/html-css.jpg">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: nearly like this.But this is not looking very well .I want to place img at the same location as where this site says" THE WORLD'S LARGEST WEB DEVELOPER SITE".Iwant an imge there above menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.
I've added a class (`.img-header`) to make image responsive. You can remove this class if you want.

I've also added `<header>` tag because you mention it in your question but it is not obligatory.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}

.img-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="img-header" src="https://www.sololearn.com/Uploads/html-css.jpg" />
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place the tag above the navigation bar. Use a good quality image which can actually be scaled upto screen width..

```css
header > img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<header><img src="https://www.sololearn.com/Uploads/html-css.jpg " alt="" /></header>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this, It will be helpfull for you.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<header>
<center><img src="https://www.sololearn.com/Uploads/html-css.jpg" /></center>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(https://www.sololearn.com/Uploads/html-css.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: white;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Check the above snippet once..

Comment: I was trying to do something else.But this idea is pretty much good than that.

Comment: Pleased to know.

Answer (score 0):

you can use background-size and padding-top to keep the image ratio if it is aonly about design.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(https://www.sololearn.com/Uploads/html-css.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-color: #333333;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  
  /* eventually */
  max-width: 800px;/* any sized wished*/
  margin: auto;
}

ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 48%;/* 325/675  gives average ratio */
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}

html {background:#74CDD3}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```